# Visual Studio: Re-enable "Build failed, run last success?" dialogue box

Tags: visual-studio

When a build fails, VS pops up with an option to run the last successful build. Someone clicked "Yes" and "Don't show this dialogue box again" on my machine, and now I'm stuck with that setting. How can I reset it?

Comment: Thank you so much for that question. Whoever thought to run the last successful build without even a notification would be a great Idea... I dont even have apropriate words for that available. Can screw up the whole test environment in worst case.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The process is as follows for `Visual Studio 2010` and above (but should be similar for previous versions):

- On the menubar go to: `'Tools' --> 'Options'`
- Go to `'Project and Solutions' --> 'Build and Run'`
- There you can find a combobox under the label `'On run, when build or deployment errors occur...'`.
- Select an appropriate option, for example `Prompt` or `Do not launch`

The process remains the same in VS2022.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in VS2023. Build fails with a number of errors  ...\Program.cs(10,19,10,30): error CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference - but I can still run the app!

Comment: This answer is 13yo and I am not using VS anymore. If things changed in VS2023 maybe we should edit this.