# Name doesnot exist in the current context error in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, entity

I have 2 methods in my class. I call `selectAll` method in `GetDb`. when I put a break point in `selectAll` method, I can see the values return in var all. Yet, when I go and find in the `GetDb` method, var list is not demonstrating the values. Truth be told it is not tossing errors moreover. When I go and find in Quick watch it is saying that:

> The name 'list' does not exist in the current context.

Am I missing anything here? Anyhelp would be really appriciated..

Here is my code:

```
private void GetDb()
{
     var list = selectAll();
}

public List<ticketinfo> selectAll()
{
     var all = db.ticketinfoes.Where(x => x.TaskType == "WINDOWSADMIN").ToList();
     return all;
}
```

Comment: usually its down to a misplaced } so theres an extra } between the GetDB and selectAll functions

Comment: In GetDb you'll need to step over the `selectAll` call before `list` will exist. Also make sure that you're in a Debug build. (The fact that you're not *using* the `list` variable at all may confuse the debugger too.) As an aside, I strongly recommend that you follow .NET naming conventions, i.e. `SelectAll` rather than `selectAll`, and `ticketInfo` instead of `TicketInfo`.)

Comment: Maybe you accidentally enabled the "Always run last succesful build" stupid feature. So you have a compilation error andVisual Studio keep executing your previous code. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925125/visual-studio-re-enable-build-failed-run-last-success-dialogue-box

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are right. I was running my program in release mode. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running my program in release mode. When I change the mode release to debug, It works fine.

Answer (score -1):

In GetDb() method assign list to any new variable like, var aaa = list; Now in debug list should have vlaue.