# Function included in header not executing, but no compile errors

Tags: c++

I have a simple main function that calls another which is included in a header.

As you can see, the main function includes main.h, as does initvars.cpp. I expect my function, when executed, to call the function initvars, which should print to the command window "Hello world" and then wait for user input to close the window.

However, I am not getting this result - when I run 'debug' in VS 2015, the command window opens and then closes immediately.

Why does this code fail to elicit the desired response?

```
//Source.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "main.h"

void main() {
    void initVars();
}


//main.h

void initvars() {
std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
std::cin.get();
}


//initvars.cpp

#ifndef _MAIN_H
#define _MAIN_H
#include <string>

void initVars();

#endif
```

Comment: FYI, void is not a valid return type for main in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to call a function, you do so by its name only without the type which is void here:

```
void main() {
  initVars();
}
```

as for why there is no compilation error, this is because the compiler considers

```
void initVars();
```

inside the main as a prototype to the function, and yes prototype can be inside functions not only in the global scope, that is why there is no errors.

as for the naming it is better to call the file containing the main function something like main.cpp and the files containing classes as classname.h and classname.cpp . Also note that you need to include the header file of your class into your cpp file.

Comment: When I do as you have said, I get a compile error: "unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl initVars(void)" (?initVars@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main conway C:\Users\ [...]". When I use my original version void initvars(); I do not get this compile error. Why is this?

Comment: you should make the v as a capital letter in initVars(), to match exactly the function call.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ghooo! Darn camel-case!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing to compile but running the last successfully compiled version.

Change

```
void main() {
    void initVars();
}
```

to

```
void main() {
    initVars();
}
```

I'd also recommend following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925125/visual-studio-re-enable-build-failed-run-last-success-dialogue-box) so that you'll be alerted to your code failing to compile more explicitly.

Comment: When I do as you have said, I get a compile error: "unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl initVars(void)" (?initVars@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main conway C:\Users\ [...]". When I use my original version void initvars(); I do not get this compile error. Why is this?