# changes in code are not being executed in debug in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I've been using vb in visual studio and changes being made in my code or form designer are not being executed in runtime. The debug mode in visual studio seems to be running an old version of my code and won't run the newer one. I've tried deleting the contents of the debug folder and allowing them to be recreated and it still ran the same older code. The form designer and code show the newer versions but just won't run them. For example i deleted as listbox and code that enters values for debugging purposes into the listbox but when i press the start button the listbox is still present and still gets populated by the test values.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Are there any message boxes between clicking Start and the program running?

Comment: Did you use existing forms from another project?

Comment: Have you checked that there are no errors in your project? If there are, you might have set it to always run the latest working build, which could be why it is running an old version. To disable this see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925168

Comment: "seems to be running an old version of my code" - this can happen if the timestamp of the compiled files are newer than the current code files.  Exit VS and delete both the "obj" and "bin" folders.