# VS is not showing me a warning dialog when I run my code even if it has mistakes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The warning window that appears when someone run a code that has a bug is not opening, because I hit don't show this message again. Does someone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio: Re-enable "Build failed, run last success?" dialogue box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925125/visual-studio-re-enable-build-failed-run-last-success-dialogue-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was already asked before:

[Visual Studio: Re-enable "Build failed, run last success?" dialogue box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925125/visual-studio-re-enable-build-failed-run-last-success-dialogue-box)

You can follow the link to solve your situation.

Comment: great thanks for the link it fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To display the Error List, choose View > Error List, or press Ctrl++E.

References: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2022)

Comment: no i didn't mean this. I meant the windows that appears when someone run a code with bugs. It says like do you want to run the last tested code... 
and then two buttons: yes or no.